# Error in fbconnect example (rouble processing "javax/net/SocketFactory.class":)

Tags: android

I am trying to publish into faceboook by using fbconnect-android sdk.
I am new to android programming.

I stuck up at the fallowing error. Please help me out.

fbconnect-sample] 
trouble processing "javax/net/SocketFactory.class":
[2010-09-28 18:06:19 - fbconnect-sample] 
Attempt to include a core VM class in something other than a core library.
It is likely that you have attempted to include the core library from a desktop
virtual machine into an application, which will most assuredly not work. If
you really intend to build a core library -- which is only appropriate as
part of creating a full virtual machine binary, as opposed to compiling an
application -- then use the "--core-library" option to suppress this error
message. If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building
an application, then please be aware that your build will still fail at some
point; you will simply be denied the pleasure of reading this helpful error
message.
[2010-09-28 18:06:19 - fbconnect-sample] 1 error; aborting
[2010-09-28 18:06:19 - fbconnect-sample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is one of those problems with Eclipse that shows itself every once in a while.

Provided that you have already ruled out your code as the problem (for me, it was a class file in the *android.jar* file, not my code) then the following is likely to solve the issue.

If you are sure that *you* have not added any code directly that is causing the issue, then try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367855/attempt-to-include-a-core-class-java-or-javax-in-something-other-than-a-cor/4368448#4368448).

If that doesn't work then try removing all JARs from your project and rebuilding the project properties:

--> Right click on the project folder (in the package explorer)

--> select "Properties"
[image: Step 1]

--> select the "Libraries" tab

--> select the libraries and click "Remove" (needs to be done for every library except for custom additions that are not the root cause, here I had to remove the *"Android 2.1 -update1"* library.)

[image: Step 2]

--> click "OK".

--> Then right click on the project folder again and select "Android Tools"

--> "Fix Project Properties" (this should add back in any libraries that you need, like the *Android* libraries)

[image: Step 3]

Then clean your project:

--> "Project Menu"

--> "Clean"

[image: Step 4]

--> "Clean All"

--> "OK"

[image: Step 5]

Now you can re-add any JARs that you had added before that your project needs, if you get the error again then you know that one of the JARs you added last is the problem and you need to find another solution (like repackaging the code away from the system packages), but that is another answer.

Hope this helps, I lost two days and some hair on this one! Sorry about the missing info and restrictions on the images, I'm bound by a contract to keep the details of my project secret until launch. Good luck!

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.
The problem is probably somewhere in the fbconnect library